# Slack in Parking Brake Line

Tags: brakes, saturn, parking-brake, sc2

I have too much slack in my parking brake. I was changing my rear drum brakes, when I was having some difficulty reattaching my parking brake line to the parking brake lever. Somehow I ended up pushing on the line, and I ended up being able to pull out about another 2 inches of slack. Now my parking brake won't engage, I can't fix it by turning the adjuster located at the parking brake handle because it's still loose at its max setting.

It's a 99 Saturn SC2.

Comment: I'm trying to picture your situation, did you pulled two inches from the lever side or the brake side? Come to mention it, a picture would go a long way here.

Comment: Did you check the other side to see if it had come loose? Not sure on the Saturn, but if it has an equalizer t-bar which feeds both brakes from a central pull, you could have dislodged the far side and now you are picking up the slack of the t-bar since it has nothing on one side which would keep it in check.

Comment: Both sides are loose originally from the drum area. Although when I took off the parking brake cover I could pull the slack from the hand brake so I think the entire thing is loose somehow. I did see a metal piece that was loose that connected to the parking brake line near the hand brake.

Comment: Any pictures? Saying there was a "metal piece that was loose" does not give us much to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its possible the cable got pushed out of the equalizer bar. Check cable connections on both ends of the cables, inside the drum and the equalizer bar. Also be sure the parking brake bar inside the drum is installed properly.

Equalizer bar image

[image]

Brake drum cable
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Pushing on the cables had disconnected them from the equalizer bar.

Comment: Hey howdy, glad you found the issue!